# Borrowed vs lent

Tags: american-english

I'm not sure which phrase to use with regards to books:

1) I borrowed this book from you.

2) you lent me this book.

3) This book is already borrowed.

4) This book is lent to...

5) This book is loaned to...

Is this the correct way to use borrow/lent/loan or is there another word for it?

Thank you

Comment: They are basically correct.  But it depends to a degree on the larger context.

Comment: Is it correct to use both lent and loaned with regards to books?

Comment: People say loaned, but strictly it's for money loaned.

Comment: "Lent" and "loaned" mean pretty much the same thing in most contexts.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - So libraries never loan books?

Comment: Libraries lend books, and banks loan money. Okay, anything can be *on loan*, and the borrowed car is a *loaner*.